# How to pass objects as argument to javascript via HtmlDocument.InvokeScript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webbrowser-control

I am using the following to invoke a javascript function from a C# application with a WebBroser control

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("function", new object[] { "arg" });
```

Is there any way to pass an object (other than string, double etc) as argument to the function test?

```
class SomeObject 
{
     int number = 0;
     string str = "1234";
}

webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("function", new object[] { new SomeObject() });
```

The above resuslts in the javascript below `typeof(args1)` returns `unknown`

```
function function(arg1) {
   alert(typeof(arg1));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is apparently quite trivial. The class `SomeObject` simply has to by marked as a COM-object like this.

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
class SomeObject 
{
     int number = 0;
     string str = "1234";
}
```

Properties can however not be accessed from Javascript.

Comment: Your answer works and also solves my problem. However even if your answer are correct it would be nice to know how you got to this conclusion.

Do you have any references that you could link that made you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score -2):

my solution might looks weired. but its work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkArgs(){
   var args = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].args;
   if(args) alert(args);
 }
</script>
...
    <body id="body" runat="server" onload="checkArgs();">
    ...
    </body>
```

and in code behind

```
this.body.Attributes["args"] = "my arguments";
```

if u use UpdatePanel, just use control that inside UpdatePanel.

edit

For passing arguments in UpdatePanel, put either control in update panel

```
<input id="args" runat="server" type="hidden"/>
or
<asp:HiddenField ID="args" runat="server"/>
```

in js change 'document.getElementsByTagName' to get element by id and use args.value

Comment: I believe UpdatePanel is part of the web namespace. I am making a Windows Forms application that is embedding af Browser Control. I need to move data from the C# application into the Javascript hosted in the browser control.

Comment: it is misleading answer. Not related to the question and may lead newbies to loose a couple of hours trying to use it.